# Android Studio generating vague variable names

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I generate methods to override the method stubs have very generic argument names (i.e int i instead of id). One example is when I override the methods for a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class. The generated method `onCreateViewHolder` has arguments with the names `ViewGroup viewGroup, int i`. Here is the actual code stub. Here the `ViewGroup` should be named `parent` and the `int` should be named `viewType`.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    return null;
}
```

How do I fix this? I have already downloaded all the sources for all the major android updates starting from jellybean.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when appropriate `Sources for Android SDK` is not installed. You should look at `build.gradle` file and check the version of `compileSdkVersion` which is defined in `android` block. After that you should open the SDK Manager and install the `Sources for Android SDK` belonging to your project `compileSdkVersion`. Do not forget restarting Android Studio after installation.

In my case, I've set the `compileSdkVersion` 28 in the project `build.gradle` file.

**Before installation of *Sources* version 28:**

```
val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher {

    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }
}
```

**After installation of *Sources* version 28:**

```
val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher {

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that already. My `compileSDKVersion` is set to 28 and I have sources for 28 installed as well. I still get generic variables. I don't know what else to do atm. I cannot reinstall it because atm I am running on mobile data.

Comment: Do you restart the AS after sources installation? (Try `invalidate cache and restart` from file menu)

Comment: Done and done. And before you tell me my installation is wrong. I installed it using all the defaults. Do I need to reinstall it from scratch after every update? I updated directly from the prompt in AS when 3.2 came out.

Comment: Update: I noticed this problem happening only with the `RecyclerView` and its classes. I have had problems with this view before in that I would have to download the `RecyclerView` library for each individual project. Though that issue fixed itself with the update to `Android Studio v3.2` .